# Java OOP Array from one class to another

Tags: java, oop

I would like to create an array that holds the information (in this case the ID) and then transfer this data into a drop down list.

The below code is where the data will be inputted and where I created the array list:

```
 Person cons_save = new Person();
 cons_save.setPersonfirstname(this.jTextField1.getText());
 cons_save.setPersonlastname(this.jTextField2.getText());
 cons_save.setPersonID(this.jTextField3.getText());
 this.jTextField1.setText("");
 this.jTextField2.setText("");
 this.jTextField3.setText("");

 cons_save.savecons();

 ArrayList<String> idList = new ArrayList<String>();

 idList.add(cons_save.PersonID);
```

I need that every time that I input the ID and save, the id will transfer to the array and go to a combo box in another field.

The code I am trying to input in the combo box is the following:

```
Object[] idList = Person.getidList();
JComboBox box = new JComboBox (idList);
```

But this keeps issuing multiple errors. I have got this code from other questions similar to mine but it is not working

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: I am stuck, this is the first time that  am using java and I am trying to search how to do it but I can't find anything

Comment: Well, you will need to add event handlers to your GUI for that. And if it's the first time you are using Java, you should start from simple tutorials, and get to GUI applications in a couple of months or so.

Comment: It would be really helpful if we could see the stack trace\exception you are  seeing.

Comment: You'll need to provide the (exact) error messages if anyone will be able to help you.  Without the error messages people can only begin to make wild guesses.

Comment: the errors are that can't find find symbol for JComboBox and getidList

Comment: Sounds strange to have both "OOP" and "Array" in the question's title...

Comment: The thing that this is an assignment, the requirements are to use oop, usually I code using c# and for things link these I use arrays to store IDs from one class to another. I am open for suggestions to any alternative solution.

Comment: Good luck using the oop.

Comment: I know its hard but step by step I am near to complete the program, this is the last step actually to cover every requirment